# implementing compareTo method for several fields

Tags: java

I want to compare two object based on 5-tuple which are:
srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol

here is what i have:

```
public class Flows implements Serializable, Comparable {

String srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol;

public int compareTo(Flows arg0) {
    if(this.srcAddr == arg0.srcAddr &&
        this.dstAddr == arg0.dstAddr &&
            this.srcPort == arg0.srcPort &&
                this.dstPort == arg0.dstPort &&
                    this.protocol == arg0.protocol)
                        return 0;
}
```

}

But it doesn't work. It says can not compare two strings.
Can anyone help me to know what is  the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: 1: use equals for comparing strings
2: the comparator must return either a negative value or positive value or 0
3: what do you mean by compare ?

Comment: i have a class which has to implement the Comparable interface to indicate how my ordering will be determined based on member fields.

Answer (score 12):

The compiler / code checker is warning you that comparing String values with `==` is almost always a mistake.

But fixing that won't really help because your code does nothing like what a correctly implemented `compareTo` method should do.

A straight-forward implementation of `compareTo` for your `Flows` class would be:

```
public int compareTo(Flows other) {
    int res = this.srcAddr.compareTo(other.srcAddr);
    if (res != 0) {
        return res;
    }
    res = this.dstAddr.compareTo(other.dstAddr);
    if (res != 0) {
        return res;
    }
    res = this.srcPort.compareTo(other.srcPort);
    if (res != 0) {
        return res;
    }
    res = this.dstPort.compareTo(other.dstPort);
    if (res != 0) {
        return res;
    }
    return this.protocol.compareTo(other.protocol);
}
```

That assumes the the fields are never null.  If they are, then write a `safeCompare(String, String)` method that takes care with nulls and apply it to each field as above.

**EDIT**

Given that you are defining `compareTo` you also ought to declare `equals` and `hashCode` to be consistent with them.  Otherwise certain collection methods are likely to behave incorrectly.

**EDIT 2**

The compiler error you mention in a comment on [how to override compareTo method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475546/how-to-override-compareto-method) happens because the `int compareTo(Flow flow)` method actually implements the compareTo method of `Comparable<Flow>`.  If you are going to declare `Flow` as implementing the raw interface type `Comparable` then the signature needs to be

```
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    Flow flow = (Flow) obj;
    ...
```

But a better solution would be to change the class declaration to:

```
public class Flows implements Serializable, Comparable<Flow> {
...
```

Comment: the purpose of compareTo is to indicate how my ordering will be determined based on member fields. such as srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol.

Comment: @Red Lion - that is what a `Comparable<T>.compareTo(<T>)` method is *supposed* to do.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Flows that) {
    return ComparisonChain.start().
        compare(this.srcAddr, that.srcAddr).
        compare(this.dstAddr, that.dstAddr).
        compare(this.srcPort, that.srcPort).
        compare(this.dstPort, that.dstPort).
        compare(this.protocol, that.protocol).
        result();
}
```

Requires [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.equals()` instead of ==.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this also, I have done like this in my project

```
public int compareTo(Flows arg0) {
    int comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4;
    comp1 = this.srcAddr.compareTo(arg0.srcAddr);
    comp2 = this.dstAddr.compareTo(arg0.dstAddr);
    comp3 = this.srcPort.compareTo(arg0.srcPort);
    comp4 = this.protocol.compareTo(arg0.protocol);

    if (comp1 == 0 && comp2 == 0 && comp3 == 0 && comp4 == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {

        if (comp1 != 0)
            return comp1;
        else {
            if (comp2 != 0)
                return comp2;
            else {
                if (comp3 != 0)
                    return comp3;
                else {
                    if (comp4 != 0)
                        return comp4;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```