# how to override compareTo method

Tags: java

here is my compareTo method, but im still getting "missing return statement" warning.
can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
    public int compareTo(Flows other) {
    if(this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr)){
        if(this.dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr)){
                 if(this.srcPort.equals(other.srcPort)){
                     if(this.dstPort.equals(other.dstPort)){
                         if(this.protocol.equals(other.protocol)){
                             return 0;
                         }
                     }
                 }
         }
 }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why is this community wiki? Secondly, think about what is returned if `this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr)` is false ;].

Comment: Believe me you cannot implement this correctly until you really know how you want to order your "MyKey" object :) First decide what is your business logic.

Comment: @Gopi, You mean, Flows objects?

Comment: @aioobe please refer previous questions by @Red Lion

Comment: What's wrong with Stephen C's answer to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449765/implementing-compareto-method-for-several-fields Why are you asking another question to begin with?

Comment: that implementation looks fine  but it doesn't implement the compareTo method. And I am getting the warning that my class is not the abstract as it doesn't override the abstract method compareTo

Comment: @Gopi: The SortedMap enables me to 'iterate' over the contents of the map in a defined order. for example, so that the flows are reported in a particular order. that's why i decides to use sortedMap and I needed to implement compareTo.

Comment: @Red Lion - I have fixed the answer.  The problem is that the signature doesn't match the interface.  You need to either implement `Comparable<Flow>` or change the compareTo method to `int compareTo(Object obj)`.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

- You get the "missing return statement" because there are paths of execution where no value is returned. For example, when the first if statement computes to false.
- You are breaking the compareTo() contract. For the following call: a.compareTo(b), the result **should** be: 0 if a equals b, <0 if a is minor than b, and >0 if a is greater than b. It seems you're using the compareTo() to check for equality, in that case the correct approach is overriding the equals() method.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an equals method. If the intention simply is to compare if the two are the same, I would do something like

```
return srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr) &&
       dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr) &&
       srcPort.equals(other.srcPort) &&
       dstPort.equals(other.dstPort) &&
       protocol.equals(other.protocol);
```

**If it's *not* the intention**, you're probably breaking the contract of compareTo since your method doesn't seem to **adhere to the transitivity requirement**. From the docs of `Comparable`:

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive

Comment: I m using sortedMap and I need to implement compareTo method to have my fields in a order that I desire to. that is why I am going that way.

Comment: Well, just keep in mind that your compareTo method must implement a relation on Flow objects that is *transitive*.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there's a possibility in your code for the compareTo to return nothing! Think about if all of those if statements fail, then it will hit the end of the method and not have returned anything. You need a return further down:

```
public int compareTo(Flows other) {
  if(this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr)){
      if(this.dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr)){
          if(this.srcPort.equals(other.srcPort)){
              if(this.dstPort.equals(other.dstPort)){
                  if(this.protocol.equals(other.protocol)){
                      return 0;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return 1;
```

}

Also you are not doing a complete compare. You need to return 0 if they are equal, less than 0 if the difference is less than and greater than 0 if it's greater. It seesm you'd be better off with overriding equals!

Maybe something like:

```
public boolean equals(Flows other) {
    return (this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr) && this.dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr) && this.srcPort.equals(other.srcPort) && this.dstPort.equals(other.dstPort) && this.protocol.equals(other.protocol));
```

Comment: im comparing 5 fields of two object just to see if there already exist that object or not. the equality is my interest in this case.

Comment: Then override the equals method instead

Comment: i have. but im using a sortedMap data structure. i need to implement the compareTo, equal and hashCode. i did the other two but not compareTo.
the purpose of compareTo is to check the order not equality.

Comment: The purpose of compareTo is to compare two objects and indicate the order in which they should be sorted. So, in what order do you want to have 2 Flows sorted?

Comment: yes you are right. i wasn't thinking in a right way. my goal was getting a new packet, check whether i already have it or not with this method. which is not essential and applicable.

Answer (score 0):

just add a "return 1" (or anything) at the end of the function, and it should solve the issue.

Comment: public int compareTo(Flows other) {
        if(this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr)){
            if(this.dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr)){
                     if(this.srcPort.equals(other.srcPort)){
                         if(this.dstPort.equals(other.dstPort)){
                             if(this.protocol.equals(other.protocol)){
                                 return 0;
                             }
                         }
                     }
            }
        }
        else
            return 1;
        
    }

Comment: You said "`return 1` (or anything)" - That will solve the compilation error issue, but not the `compareTo` contract violation issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will compile and run, but what about the rest of the contract?  Where's less than and greater than?

```
public int compareTo(Flows other) {

    int value = 0;

    if(this.srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr)){
        if(this.dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr)){
                 if(this.srcPort.equals(other.srcPort)){
                     if(this.dstPort.equals(other.dstPort)){
                         if(this.protocol.equals(other.protocol)){
                             value = 0;
                         }
                     }
                 }
         }

    return value;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I see that, but that breaks the compareTo contract.